# request two files with one JQuery Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have two JSON files I'm pulling into my web page. Is there a way to call both files in one function?

Here's how mine is set up:

```
    var getData = $.getJSON("data/fileOne.json", function (data) {
        damageRecordsToArray(data); //function call

    });

    var getData = $.getJSON("data/fileTwo.json", function (data) {
        geoJsonPointsToArray(data); //function call

    });
```

Comment: In one *function* (as your description states)? Yes - make both calls in that function. In a single *request* (as your title states)? No, as they are two separate files. If you want to make a single request you will need to merge both JSON files in to one.

Comment: Yes, I don't intend to combine the files. I've never made a jQuery call in a function so I'll fiddle around with that.

Comment: Just FYI there's no such thing as a jQuery function. It's just a plain old JS function. In other words, just place both your current `$.getJSON` calls in a function: `function foo() { /* your code here */ }` then you can re-use it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan would you mind providing a more detailed example of how you would write it please?

Comment: If you have some server side code, may be like node, probably you can create a api which can listen to some url and return both the json files in the same request

Comment: @Matt sure, but it's exactly as I outlined above: https://jsfiddle.net/jtfa5owv/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of jquery to call both of your files inside of a single call. I think this is what you were looking for. If so, try the code below.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/09jLkvef/

```
var urls = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'
];

$(function() {
  $.when.apply($, urls.map(function(url) {
    return $.getJSON(url);
  })).done(function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  });
});
```

Once you open that fiddle up, bring up your console and you'll see both sets of data returned. Is that what you meant?